# Java: Could someone explain this from "Thinking in Java 4th edition"?

Tags: java, binary, hex, bitwise-operators

I simply don't understand what the author means with this exercise. Especially the part about how the two constants are supposed to be built.

Could someone maybe give an example or explain this a bit further?

"Write a program with two constant values, one with alternating binary ones and zeroes, with a zero in the least-significant digit, and the second, also alternating, with a one in the least-significant digit (hint: It’s easiest to use hexadecimal constants for this). Take these two values and combine them in all possible ways using the bitwise operators, and display the results using Integer.toBinaryString( )"

Edit (my solution):

Is this right?

```
public class BitwiseOperators {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int bit1 = Integer.parseInt("10101010", 2);
        int bit2 = Integer.parseInt("01010101", 2);


        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bit1 & bit2));
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bit1 ^ bit2));
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bit1 | bit2));
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bit1 << bit2));
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bit1 >> bit2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you can define these two constants as

```
int a = Integer.parseInt("10101010", 2);
int b = Integer.parseInt("01010101", 2);
```

Then you can use bitwise operations on these two and display the results with 
`Integer.toBinaryString( )`.

```
// sample bitwise operation
int c = b & a;
```

Comment: I added my solution, is this right? What do you think? @johnsmith

Comment: maybe you can add one more,  `>>>`?